# Django check array inside array and change template

Tags: arrays, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

i have array line this

```
setime = ["00:00", "00:30", "01:00", "01:30", "02:00", "02:30", "03:00", "03:30", "04:00", "04:30", "05:00", "05:30", "06:00", "06:30", "07:00", "07:30", "08:00", "08:30", "09:00", "09:30", "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30", "12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30", "15:00", "15:30", "16:00", "16:30", "17:00", "17:30", "18:00", "18:30", "19:00", "19:30", "20:00", "20:30", "21:00", "21:30", "22:00", "22:30", "23:00", "23:30"]
```

and i want check

**in view**

```
 myListTime= checkDateTime.objects.all().filter(Teacher_id = 1)
```

**i tried in template**

```
{% for i in setime %}
                <ul>
                    {% for j in myListTime %}
                        {% if j.cuTime in i %}
                            <li class="active">{{ i }}</li>
                        {% else %}
                            <li>{{ i }}</li>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
                {% endfor %}
```

i need result like this if data matched, li have active class

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXl7I.png)

[in db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMyVC.png)

Comment: How does the time value link to the `checkDateTime` objects? Is there a field for it?

Comment: sry for lack information i re edited my question. I tried {% if j.cuTime in i %} this in my template.But not working.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than iterating over the list of times, you'd be better to use that list in your database query.

If you've got a list you can do `__in` to check if a list of values exists in the values for a field.

```
setime = ["00:00", "00:30", ..., "22:30", "23:00", "23:30"] 

myListTime_with_time = checkDateTime.objects.all().filter(Teacher_id=1, cuTime__in=setime)

myListTime_without_time = checkDateTime.objects.all().filter(Teacher_id=1).exclude(cuTime__in=setime)
```